# Want to publish 1500 events in 10 mins duration in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jmeter script in which I want to publish 1500 events in 10 mins duration.
Is it possible to configure this using "Ultimate Thread Group" or "Throughput Shaping Timer"?
If yes, then how?

I tried using the default thread group in which I used "Number of threads" to 30 & "Loop Count" as 50, so as to make 1500 events. But, how can I achieve this to publish 1500 events in 10 mins?

I am using JMS Point-to-Point as my Sampler.

Comment: have you tried using Thread Pools or concurrent Threads executers?

Comment: Are those Jmeter Plugins?

Answer (score 0):

try using Runtime Controller - The Runtime Controller controls how long its children are allowed to run.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller